# Chrome does not render pdf file

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-docs-api

We are developing an Android app which must render pdf files stored on server in mobile browser (Chrome) through google docs viewer. URL of files are passed to the viewer in the following manner:

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=<public URL of pdf file>
```

However, it is observed that the files is rendered as html and not as pdf. What could be the issue?

Comment: Chrome cannot display pdf´s to begin with. And google docs will convert all documents to html to be visible in a browser.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138487/how-does-the-google-docs-pdf-viewer-work) if it can help you.